# Improve performance of Rails application by adding indexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

In my Rails application I have an index view that lists all of my `projects`.

This list can be sorted by clicking on any of the table column headers, e.g. `Date`, `Name`, `updated_at` etc. This happens by appending a `&sort=` GET parameter to the URL.

My question is: From a performance point-of-view, would it be advisable to add indexes to these columns in my database?

This is what a migration might look like:

```
class AddMoreIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :projects, :date
    add_index :projects, :name
    add_index :projects, :update_at
  end
end
```

Will I get any performance gains from this?

Comment: It really depends on how you are querying the db, reading or writing more, db size, which db you're using and a plethora of other factors... Best way to find out is to run benchmarks.

Comment: I don't think it really depends on anything. If you perform search on a column you have to have an index on it. If you perform search on multiple columns there should be multi-column index. Works for all relational databases I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes can be used to speed an order-by, but if you were identifying a subset of rows to display then an index that is helpful for that is likely to be chosen in preference. You'd need composite indexes in such a situation.

There're a couple of other problems.

Firstly, ordering on an indexed string value may require a linguistically sorted index, not the regular ASCII/Binary sort, so multilingual applications may not be helped at all.

Secondly, it can discourage normalisation of the database because you really need the display values to be in the table you're selecting.

You might like to look at using another method for the sort. I've been very happy with using Google [visualisation tables](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), which come with JQuery sorting built in.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you query your database, then yes, it will give you performance gains. For example, whenever I add a foreign key to a table, I immediately index by it. Why? I know queries will be running through it in my application. If not, I wouldn't have put a foreign key. In this way, especially when you accumulate a large amount of data in your database, it will definitely give performance gains (sometimes, by an incredible amount). If you plan to query your database by `date`, `name`, or `updated at`, then yes, it could potentially be a performance gain depending on your query. Otherwise, there really is no point.

Note, you wouldn't want to add an index for every column. Having necessary indices will help you, but if you have an index for every column, then you run the risk of confusing the SQL Query Optimizer and actually hindering your performance.

My suggestion: Add an index for every foreign key you have in your table, but if you're also running some heavy queries with other columns, then add an index there too.

Comment: What about ordering on a column? Cause that's what he is asking.